# Why do PS4 controllers turn off on sign out, if the only option is to sign in again?

Tags: ps4, controllers

'Signing out' from your account on a PS4 brings you to a menu with a list of accounts you can switch to - meaning the only action you can take from there is sign into another account. However, signing out also turns off the PS4 controller.

If you were going to turn off the console, there's that option in the menu to begin with, and it signs out automatically anyways when turning off the system.

So what purpose is there for a Ps4 controller to turn off when signing out?

Answer (score 2):

When you are playing a local multiplayer game, you use a different account for each connected DualShock controller. I think the purpose of turning off the controller is to keep playing singleplayer. Because otherwise, it wouldn't be possible to sign out from the second player's account and turn off the controller at the same time.

Comment: That is something at least, though you can turn off a controller even after signing out, so it's more convenient in that sense. But you like if only 1 person is on, it's just annoying mostly having to turn the controller back on.